# What is the use of + operator in the function parameter type?

Tags: rust, async-await

I came across this syntax while learning async & await:

```
fn spawn(&self, future: impl Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send)
```

What is the role of `+` sign in the `future` parameter type?

[Link](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/04_executor.html) to the guide I'm following.

Comment: `+` is the symbol to combine the traits and lifetimes which are expected for a type. (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#specifying-multiple-trait-bounds-with-the--syntax)

Comment: @prog-fh Is there some doc for this. I tried but couldn't search for it as searching for + doesn't give me results what I expect.

Comment: TRPL has [a section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html?highlight=bounds#specifying-multiple-trait-bounds-with-the--syntax) that describes using `+` to combine trait bounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @trentcl. There's a ton of info on that page which I missed.